# How do I create a Facebook Open Graph action on the Timeline which lies in the future?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-timeline, open-graph-beta

I know I can create an action in the present and in the past. But is it possible to create one which lies in the future? For example I would like the users of my app to be able to make an appointment in a restaurant via the timeline for the next day.
I have tried the following code:

```
function postRestaurant() {
    FB.api('me/APP_NAMESPACE:have_lunch?\
    start_time=2011-12-12T04:00:00&\
    expires_in=7200&\
    restaurant=' + encodeURIComponent(getRedirectURI() + '?type=restaurant' + '&description=dynamicdescription' + '&title=dynamictitle'), 'post', function (response) {
        if (!response || response.error) {
            console.log('postRestaurant: Error occured => ' + response.error.message);
        } else {
            console.log('postRestaurant: Post was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
        }
    });
}
```

With this code I can create an action in the present and it also works when creating the action in the past, but it doesn't want to create the action in the future. When I set a start_time which lies in the future I always end up with an action on my timeline which has already happened just now: Lego had lunch at... So now I am wandering whether it is even possible? I haven't found any info on that matter in the documentation. Maybe you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK it is not possible. The [documentation page for facebook open graph actions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/actions/#timestamps) has a section which tells about possible configuration of timestamps:

> Action’s timestamps can be configured to describe actions that occur
>   at different times and how actions appear on the user's profile and
>   News Feed.
>
> Supported configurations for timestamps are:
>
> - Point in time when the API call is made (default. example: voted for    a poll)
> - Start in the past / end in the past (example: soccer team I played on    last summer)
> - Start in the past / end in the future (example: courses a student    takes over a semester
> - Start now / end in the future (example: a relationship status)
> - Start now / end indefinite (example: like or want actions)